# Progress bar in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, progress-bar

I want to create a progressbar that looks like a cylinder in wpf, just like the following image (here it's made in winform) :

[image: Cylinder progressbar]

Can anyone show me how to do it, or maybe give me a trick? Thank you

Comment: This might Help [Progress Bar](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/814902/The-Problem-of-Unwanted-WPF-ProgressBar-Animation)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to edit Template of progressbar  for this.See **[Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd334413%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)** of Progressbar

**Edited Template/Style**

```
 <Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                    <Grid x:Name="TemplateRoot">
                        <Border Margin="5,0,5,0"  BorderThickness="0,1.2,0,1.2"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <Rectangle  x:Name="PART_Track"/>
                        <Grid x:Name="PART_Indicator" ClipToBounds="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <Grid x:Name="Indicator">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle Margin="0,0,-3,0" Grid.Column="1" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
                                <Ellipse Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Ellipse Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Rectangle Margin="5,0,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"></Rectangle>
                                <Border  Grid.Column="1"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="-5,0,-2,0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <Grid  x:Name="Animation">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Ellipse Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Grid.Column="2" StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Rectangle   Grid.Column="1"  RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
                                    <Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                        <ScaleTransform/>
                                    </Rectangle.RenderTransform>
                                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                                        <VisualBrush Stretch="None">
                                            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                                                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Foreground}">
                                                    <TextBlock  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"  Text="{Binding Path=Value,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Foreground="Black">
                                                        <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90"></RotateTransform>
                                                        </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
                                                    </TextBlock>
                                                </Grid>
                                            </VisualBrush.Visual>
                                        </VisualBrush>
                                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                                </Rectangle>
                                <Ellipse Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="10" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"/>
                                <Rectangle   Margin="5,0,0,0" Fill="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"></Rectangle>
                                <Border  Grid.Column="1"  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Margin="-5,0,-2,0" BorderThickness="0,1,0,1"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                        <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Right" Height="{Binding Path=Width,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"  StrokeThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Stroke="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" Width="8" Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Orientation" Value="Vertical">
                            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform" TargetName="TemplateRoot">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <RotateTransform Angle="-90"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsIndeterminate" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" TargetName="Indicator" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <ProgressBar  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#95928A" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="#E2E2E2" Foreground="#D4BC39" Margin="30" Width="30" IsIndeterminate="False" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="30" Height="150" />
    <ProgressBar  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#95928A" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="#E2E2E2" Foreground="#D4BC39" Margin="30" Width="30" IsIndeterminate="False" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="47.5" Height="150" />
    <ProgressBar  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#95928A" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="#E2E2E2" Foreground="#D4BC39" Margin="30" Width="30" IsIndeterminate="False" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="75" Height="150" />
    <ProgressBar  BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#95928A" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"  Background="#E2E2E2" Foreground="#D4BC39" Margin="30" Width="30" IsIndeterminate="False" Orientation="Vertical" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="100" Height="150" />
</StackPanel>
```

**Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Visit this webpage.They do using windows form but the logic can be applied in wpf.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/johndouglas/ProgressarBarWithCylinderEffect11152005234729PM/ProgressarBarWithCylinderEffect.aspx

Comment: I saw it before posting this question. the logic can't be really applied on an amvvm architecture. Thank you @Harun ergül

Comment: I found this link http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/HelixToolkit.Wpf .This may be usefull